# git post-receive hook not running with client

Tags: git, jenkins

We have an internal git repo server and we try to clone the git for some branch on local machines.

We need to trigger Jenkins build once a commit is pushed into repo.

Tried to use "post-commit" hook, but it does not reflect the lat change in cloned git repo.
Even tried to use "post-receive" or "post-push" hooks, but it does not even get called. I have also added echo command to check if it displays.

The main reason for doing this is, when a developer checks-in his changes to git repo, Jenkins build should automatically trigger the job with latest changes.
NOTE: we are using git repo and not github.

Any other way to perform or any suggestions on this would be helpful.
TIA

Comment: You should put your code in post-receive hook. What do you mean it is not even called?

Comment: Did you put `post-receive` under the repo on the server? Was it executable?

Comment: @Andrija, It was not even called means I had added an echo command and that was also not displayed.

Comment: @ElpieKay, I need to trigger builds based on latest commit from client only. I tried to use "curl -v http://server/git/notifyCommit?url=[repo_url]" in post-commit hook, it triggers the job successfully but latest changes are not reflected.

Comment: `git commit` is a local action. Is the node that runs the Jenkins build job the same machine with the one where your local repository is? If not, have you pushed the new commit to a remote repository so that the build job can fetch the new commit?

Comment: Put that echo command in `post-receive` hook on server. Next time when you push to that server it has to be triggered. Have you tried that, exactly?